# Is it possible to edit Google Drive's spreadsheet using some HTTP API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Is it really possible to directly edit content of a spreadsheet that is located on some Google Drive account from, lets say PHP application?

Is there an API available with granular operations or do I need to download/edit/upload the whole document every time?

Is it also possible to call my script via HTTP when changes are made to this document by user?

Is there any examples of such functionality in PHP or similar technology?

Comment: 1) https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: 2) No, you can't get called your script via HTTP. You have to monitor the document on your own.